# Error con las sesiones en php

Tags: php, sesiones

Tengo un problema con las sesiones en php.

He realizado un desarrollo en php para hacer un panel de administración, con el login y la primera vez que accedo, me dice que la sesión no se ha creado. Pero a la segunda, ya entra sin problemas.
Esto pasa siempre la primera vez que entro después de iniciar el navegador.

El esquema es:

pagina index.php con el formulario  (primera linea es session_start(); )
Al hacer submit al formulario va a un php que es login.php (cuya primera linea es session_start();)

En el login.php "instancio" una clase que es la que comprueba en la base de datos que el usuario es correcto. En esta clase, para comprobar, escribo en el log las variables que se crean en la sesión y lo hace correctamente.

Si el login es correcto, lo redirigo a la página dentro ya del panel (dashboard.php)
La redirección es header('Location: '. 'midominio.com/control/dashboard');

Y en el dashboard.php la primera linea es un require_once( **DIR** .'/../sessions.php'); y la primera linea de session.php es session_start();.

Y a continuación escribo en el log las variables de la sesión y me las escribe vacías.

He estado mirando otros hilos para buscar una solución, y no he conseguido que funcione.

¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que puede pasar?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Para que la sesion te funcione en cualquier pagina, debes iniciarla primero. Trata de poner session_start() en la primera linea en todas las paginas. Si no las tienes asi.

Comment: La primera linea de cada pagina es un include a un php cuya primera linea es session_start(); Al escribir la pregunta, lo había indicado pero luego no se ha visto.

Answer (score 0):

Seguro que lo que te está pasando es que pierdes las variables de sesión al redirigir tras el login.

Asegúrate de guardar los datos de sesión antes de redirigir, mediante la función session_write_close().

Suponiendo que rediriges con header():

```
session_write_close();
header('Location: ......');
exit;
```

Es importante hacer exit; justo después de la redirección, para asegurarte que el script termine ahí.

Puedes crear una función para redirigir evitando tener que escribir esas líneas siempre que redirijas:

```
function redirigir($url)
{
    session_write_close();
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Gracias José Carlos por tu respuesta. Lo he probado y sigue fallando. La primera vez que se hace login no hay sesión, pero las siguientes ya si que hay sesión. Eso es lo que más me mosquea. Y no veo el error.

Comment: No sé, tendría que ver el código.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo¿Que puedo hacer para que lo veas? ¿Te doy acceso a mi hosting?¿pongo aquí todo el código de los ficheros involucrados?. Muchas gracias José Carlos

Comment: Búscame en Google y escríbeme, y ya seguimos el hilo por ahí.